# WampServer 2.5 php-win.exe task

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver, windows-process

WampServer 2.5 starts a php-win.exe process on (re-)start.

This process uses a lot of CPU and I/O, causing slowdowns on one of my harddisks and effectively 100% use of one of my CPU cores.

I typically just kill the process manually, which doesn't seem to affect anything in any way.

But I would rather the process didn't start at all, or somehow use less CPU and I/O.

What does the php-win.exe process do and how I can change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php-win.exe is the php command line processor but one that does not need a dos box to run in.

It is used by WAMPServer as most of WAMPServer uses PHP to do most of its stuff.

If this initial processing is causing the problems you suggest it is odd as the startup processing done in PHP usually takes milli second.

It would suggest that something is wrong somewhere.

These WAMPServer startup processes do report errors into the PHP error log so I would suggest you look in there for some clues.

Comment: You were completely right. I tend to move the www folder out of the the wamp folder to make it more accessible. The script `config.inc.php` contains a hardcoded path `$wwwDir`, which caused `refresh.php` to loop infinitely on a `readdir()` statement thanks to an unchecked file handle.

Comment: You should leave the www folder untouched. If you want to move your site code else where, and thats a good idea, I would suggest using Virtual Hosts to do that. You also get many other less obvious benefits when you have a VH for each of your projects. This was written for V2.5, but applies to any version http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Comment: I pretty much already did what the answer you linked to mentioned except I moved the www directory instead of just creating a new www directory elsewhere and leaving the original in tact. This moving is what triggered the error. I don't quite know what kind of functionality you lose by not changing the hardcoded path in `config.inc.php`, but apparently it's not very important.